# Coefficient of relatedness for a locus on the Z chromosome

Tags: genetics, population-genetics, chromosome, sex-chromosome

So i know that the ZW determination system is the equivalent for XY in birds. Moreover, I know that the coefficient of relatedness between siblings for the X chromosome is 0.5 so im guessing that the coefficient of relatedness between siblings for the Z chromosome is the same ??

Comment: Yes it would be .5 Due to reasons you correctly deduced

Comment: but isnt it different between brother and sister and between sisters and between brothers. Isnt the Z chromosome considered as haploidiploid ?